# Python - How to sort a list of lists by last element of another list of lists?

Tags: python, sorting, vector

I have a list of n value vectors and a list of n time vectors. I would like to sort the time vectors based on the last element of each value vector. I thought of appending to each time vector the last element of the corresponding value vector, then using

```
time_vector.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1]) #or
time_vector.sort(key=itemgetter(-1))
```

and finally popping out the last element of each time vector.
However, I'm thinking there must be a simpler manner to do this. I haven't been able to find any example for this problem in the Python reference for sort and sorted.

Expanded Question using Alex-Martelli's proposed solution. Because I have to reorder both value vectors v_v and time vectors t_v, Alex offers a one-stop solution

```
(v_v, t_v) = zip(*sorted (zip(v_v, t_v),key=lambda v: v[0][-1]))
```

I do not understand how unzipping works, but I just copied it from Python's documentation, and it works. The additional question is why this doesn't work using itemgetter() instead of lambda, and why it doesn't work with the vector.sort() method instead of using the function sorted()

The numerical examples I used to test the above are

```
v_v = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [5, 3, 4]]
t_v = [[1, 1], [5, 6], [9, 8], [3, 10, 1]]
```

which produce the sorted result of

```
v_v = ([3, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 3, 4])
t_v = ([9, 8], [1, 1], [5, 6], [3, 10, 1])
```

Comment: `time_vector.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])` if a good way to do this. Why doesn't it work for you? How big is `n`?

Comment: @PavelReznikov, sorting `time_vector` (whose values, the Q makes it clear, are irrelevant to the desired order) ignoring `values_vector` (whose last items is the only determinant of the desired ordered, again per the Q) clearly can't work.  The `lambda` gets an `x` that's an item of `time_vector` -- it's supposed to ignore it and instead somehow getting the corresponding item of `value_vector` (last subitem thereor) -- **how**?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the two vectors are -- and apparently need to remain! -- separate, this is a case for good old DSU -- decorate, sort, undecorate.

```
result = [t for v, t in
          sorted(zip(value_vector, time_vector), key=lambda vt: vt[0][-1])]
```

The addition of the `key=` arg has almost done away with the need to understand DSU in most cases -- it does the decoration for you (as long as it's just a function of each item) and the undecoration after the sort too.

But here, the sort key is **not** just a function of the item -- it's a function of the item's **position** in the list, which you use to index a separate parallel list (a very unusual arrangement of data in Python).  Yet you want to sort the *times* (even though per se they have absolutely nothing to do with the desired order!) -- that's the crux of the difficulty.

Alternatively, consider sorting the positions, then using those to reorder the times.  That may feel a bit less weird:-).  It can be collapsed into a single statement, but it may be clearer when presented as two:

```
idx_val = sorted(enumerate(value_vector), key=lambda i, v: v[-1])
result = [times_vector[i] for i, _ in idx_val]
```

I think this may be clearer because the `idx_val` (properly sorted list of `(index, value)` pairs where we don't actually care about the `value` further but need it for the sorting) isn't "glued on" to the times then has to be ripped off again -- rather we just use the indices in the list comprehension.  And the naming and the splitting into two steps helps.

(But of course if you're a "one statement to rule them all" fiend you can substitute the `sorted` call into the listcomp in lieu of the `idx_val` name and get back to a single statement -- no real advantage at all, but, to the wrong sort of people, "cooler":-)]

Added: another guise of DSU would be an `OrderedDict` -- just a different way to "undecorate", really.  But there's a commenter mentioning it, so here it is -- you be the judge of whether it offers any value.

```
import collections
od = collections.OrderedDict(
    sorted(zip(value_vector, time_vector),
           key=lambda v, t: v[-1]))
result = list(od.values())
```

I actually think that by hiding the undecorating in the keys/values play of a `dict` subclass, it makes things murkier.  But, de gustibus...

Comment: what about using `OrderedDict` ?

Comment: @KasraAD, what about it?  Still pretty much a DSU there.

Comment: yah , its nice idea and i gave my vote too :) but i mean is it good here too ? or maybe not ?

Comment: @KasraAD, let me make you happy by editing my A to include that alternative too.

Comment: thanks , but the only reason that i ask this question is because of that i have encountered to same problem already , and as i remember i read on some where that `Orderedict` could be a good choice ! its that all :) hope i could get may answer with edit , thanks again

Comment: I suppose another alternative is something like: `sorted(time_vector, key=lambda L, i=iter(value_vector): next(i)[-1])`

Comment: @JonClements, yes, *clever* way to exploit incidentalia such as the once-and-for-all binding of this `lambda`'s `i=` argument.  However there's no constraint on `sorted` to call the `key` in the exact order in which `time_vector`'s items occurs, so while I think it would work in today's CPython versions, it's to some extent an implementation accident that it does.  Which helps explain why in the Python community "*clever*" is a four-letter word (quite a compression trick, hm?-).

Comment: @AlexMartelli indeed... I'd go with `zip` as the most understandable and accurate, but just thought I'd throw it out there :p

Comment: @Alex-Martinelli, I like the first solution, thanks! Could you add the missing  closed square bracket at the end of your code? I tried to correct it but it won't let me for a change that short. I have three side questions on your solution, and perhaps I should add them to the bottom of my initial question: (1) using sort method; (2) using itemgetter; (3) reordering values and time vectors at the same time as a tuple of vectors.

Comment: @gciriani, `]` added, tx.  `sort` rather than `sorted` using DSU would require first building a separate auxiliary list on which you can call `sort` then extracting the results from it -- zero advantage, some disadvantage.  `itemgetter` is fine when it applies but it's insufficient here as you need two layers of indexing and it gives only one.  To reorder multiple lists the same way, the `idx_val` solution shines brighter and brighter as you can use that indexes-sequence as many times as needed.

Comment: @gciriani, BTW, Martinelli (here in the US) is a brand of cider (founded by Swiss immigrants) -- my surname's spelled "Martelli":-)

Comment: @Alex-Martelli, thanks for your help. I see we have a few things in common, except for programming skills, that is :-)